# Upgrade from 2013 SP1 HR1 with CWA to Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, upgrade, 2013-sp1-hr1

We are planning to upgrade from Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 to SDL Web 8.5. On the presentation side we are using CWA with dynamic views, all of our pages are published to broker as JSPs. All JSPs are having java scriptlets, with content delivery api calls, to add dynamic CP on the page at run time. Also we have a lot of static and dynamic Component Templates.

With Upgrade, looking for a similar delivery mechanism where JSP with java sciptlet can be published from CMS and compiled at run time. Not sure whether it is possible with DXA or not.

Any idea on how to achieve that or any suggestions on upgrade path for the application?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow SDL official [Upgrade documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-E6995D0C-804C-4399-8EB1-044E64C33A12). if not already using DXA, Shifting now means re-writing your application.